# Windows 2012 with nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, vpn, windows-server-2012, reverse-proxy

I'm planning on upgrading my server to windows 2012. One thing I'm trying to wrap my head around is how to get things working together with nginx.

**Question:**

I'm planning on making use of both vpn and remote web access when we move to win2012.

My question is, how do I get set up nginx so that those things can be accessed via domain.com? I'd like to be able to access remotewebaccess by visiting domain.com/remote for example.
Is there a way to set up a reverse proxy (like with my other services) to accomplish this? Or is there another preferred method for getting all my services, plus the new win2012 ones, to work together?

What are the correct steps to accomplish a setup where I have nginx, rwa+vpn, my current services, all being accessed through domain.com on 443?

**Background information:**

I have a domain purchased through namecheap.com, but going to migrate it over to godaddy so it can be used with win2012.

Currently, nginx is set up with reverse proxy so things like seafile (cloud service), couch potato, plex, sonarr, can be accessed by visiting www.domain.com/couchpotato (for example)

nginx listens on both port 80 and 443 as I have my own SSL certificate. Any requests to 80 get redirected to 443 so I'm always using SSL when I access any web service

A possible issue with the intended setup, is that port 443 is used by nginx for all of those services. I heard that remote web access also uses 443, so there will be a clash there (I guess unless I set it up through nginx too)

Currently, I forward ports 80 and 443 to my server using the router, and domain.com just points to the routers IP. I'm unfamiliar with how win2012 actually makes use of a domain name that has been registered with it so I'm thinking I need to do things a different way?

Comment: This is a very broad question, with a lot of things that need to be covered.  You will get a better response if you do some more investigation and then come back with smaller, more focused questions on individual points you're struggling with.

Comment: I guess my specific question is how do you set up a reverse proxy in nginx to be able to access rwa and vpn? Is that even possible? The rest of it is just information that may or may not be useful in understanding the situation overall

Comment: You may wish to revise your question to make that more clear.  Many people don't read comments.

Comment: The big question is why you want nginx on windows? I guess it still not ready for production.

Comment: for seafile I have found IIS to be much more unstable than nginx. I don't know if its a seafile thing or an IIS thing, but regardless, nginx seemed the more stable way to go, and is also faster to set up. Now that things are already set up, I'd prefer to stay this way